# How to delete characters in a string if found special characters?

Tags: java, string, boolean

I have a String and a boolean, and if there is an * in the String and the boolean is true it will ignore everything before the * and only return the characters after *. But if the boolean is false it will return what is before the * and delete everything after.

example:
     "abc*def", true -> def

```
       "abc*def", false -> abc
```

What the boolean do is, if true, ignore everything before the * and I don't know how to do this. What i want to know is if I can read the String and if * remove from charAt(0) to charAt(*). something like this.

Comment: start with string.split

Comment: Read the [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) API, there are some methods there that will do just what you need.  (P.S. I would _not_ use `split`.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unclear what part of the Javadoc for String doesn't cover this, and the OP has shown no attempt at solving it themselves.

Comment: Sorry if it seems unclear, but I'm just beginning in programming and Java and don't know all the methods

Comment: That's why we have Javadoc - it's there to tell you what methods are available and give you a high level overview of what they do. Here's the Javadoc for the `String` class in Java 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
String something(String value, boolean b) {
    return value.split("*")[b ? 1 : 0];
}
```

Split on `*`, if `b`, return the last part, else return the first part.

Comment: `something("abcdefg",true)`?

Comment: crash, but not relevant to the question. `something(null, true)` crashes too. I provide an simple answer to a question, I leave input sanitation to the OP.

Comment: how does this [b ? 1 : 0] work. How does it choose the first or second part of the split.

Comment: this is called `boolean ternary operator`. it means `if b then 1 else 0` this gives the index in the split string array, which at this point is `["abc", "def"]`

Comment: @Camilo: It's called ternary operator, the syntax is A ? B : C and is equal to `if A is true, take B, otherwise take C`

Comment: @njzk2 It is relevant, because he didn't say the string would contain a `*`--he said "**if** there is an * in the String" implying that there might not be.  But it can be hard to tell for sure.

Comment: @ajb: I think in the question the case where there is no * but the boolean is true is not defined. the 3 other cases are covered by my snippet. I'm satified with that, and java is too verbose to handle that sort of things in short and nice code.